# Load external HTML file into div with Brackets

Tags: jquery, html

Sorry if this is a silly question but no other solutions from other times this has been asked have helped me.

I am trying to display the content of a separate HTML file into a div that displays on multiple pages, so I don't have to go out of my way to copy and paste it repeatedly when I make changes to it.

I am hosting locally in my chrome browser and using Brackets editor.

Here is an example that basically summarizes what I'm trying to do-

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#content').load("content.html");
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="content"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

and here is what I want to have displayed in the #content div:

content.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
    </head>

    <body>

        <p>Hello!</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

I saw something about `.load()` not working if you host locally, is that the issue here? :( How can I fix this? I'm new to coding.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of methods to insert the content lets beginn with the best

The html import tag

[Treehouse aricle](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/introduction-html-imports&ved=2ahUKEwjE0ovEj4TdAhUktYsKHY1UD5oQFjAFegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw2MC7v--XKBx_vgkLu5Z_m4&cshid=1535059982391)
Its a way that has many benefits like ist short af ,
but comes up with problems like : the compatibility is worse across the browsers.

The jquery method

as described in the official docs there is the method `.load()` and it althought has an completion handler

```
$("#content").load("path/to/local/file.html", function (){
console.log("success");
});
```

The manual ajax

Dont do this , only if you know what your calling or if your project isnt time limited abd you want to know what there is going on

There are many sides that explain how to perform this method , but many people thought this and many build something to provide easy access , so if your new to coding , this wont fit your problem

There are many more with crazy object manipulation and complex scripts. I would recommend the first if you know that only you or someone who is willing to enable experimental settings will use this.

Any other project that should result in quick responses and releases try jquery. 
Try to explore this with an debugger 
Try to check the console output.

If you finde something in there or an unexpected behaviour , post it and ill do my best to help you out